# python. I can not convert numbers from a txt file to a verifier with int

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I generate an array with python and then I save it in a txt file. When I recover it and I try to convert it into an array, and I work with it, it gives me the error:

> ufunc 'multiply' did not contain a loop with signature matching types
>   dtype('

This is the code:

```
import numpy as np

lista=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
vector=np.array(lista)
print (vector)
lista.append(9)
vector=np.array(lista)
print (vector)
archivo= open('datos.txt','w')

archivo.write('%s'%vector)

archivo=open('datos.txt','r')
dades=archivo.read()


vector2=np.array(dades)

print(vector2)
print(vector2*2)
```

Can you help me?. Thank

Comment: There's multiple issues. First, you don't actually close the file before trying to read it back in (buffer might not have been flushed to disk) and second, why don't you use [`savetxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) which will be in a format that `numpy` understands, rather than a string representation of an array

Answer (score 0):

When you read it in `dades=archivo.read()` you actually get a 19-char string.

In order to turn this into a NumPy array you need to do some processing:

```
>>> dades_as_ints = list(map(int, dades[1:-1].split()))
>>> vector2 = np.array(dades_as_ints)
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

>>> vector2 * 2
array([ 2,  4,  6,  8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18])
```

I would suggest you look at [numpy docs savetxt](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html#numpy.savetxt), which will store your array in a human readable format, or `numpy.save` for efficient store/load.

Comment: Yes. It's OK. Thans you very much for your answer.

Comment: Feel free to accept it as an answer if you feel it sufficiently answers your question! @MIGUELANGELMartinez